# How to get children's folder name in google Drive using java

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I am working with Google Drive API in java. I got children's Folder Id in my code but I want Children's Folder name. I applied all method to get Children's folder name but I did not get

```
Drive.Children.List FolderID = service.children().list(child.getId());
```

from this code I got Folder Id like 0B3-sXIe4DGz1c3RhcnRlcl9.

```
 Drive.Children.List Foldername = service.children().list(child.getId().getClass().getName());
```

In this code it returns {folderId=java.lang.String}

How can I get the name of the folder?

Comment: What do you expect ``getClass().getName()`` to return other than the class name?

Answer (score 0):

In Google drive folders are files.  You have the folder id use [Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) to return the [FileResource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) which contains the title of the folder.

Code ripped from documentation for [Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get)

```
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

// ...

public class MyClass {

  // ...

  /**
   * Print a file's metadata.
   *
   * @param service Drive API service instance.
   * @param fileId ID of the file to print metadata for.
   */
  private static void printFile(Drive service, String fileId) {

    try {
      File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();

      System.out.println("Title: " + file.getTitle());
      System.out.println("Description: " + file.getDescription());
      System.out.println("MIME type: " + file.getMimeType());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Download a file's content.
   *
   * @param service Drive API service instance.
   * @param file Drive File instance.
   * @return InputStream containing the file's content if successful,
   *         {@code null} otherwise.
   */
  private static InputStream downloadFile(Drive service, File file) {
    if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
      try {
        HttpResponse resp =
            service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl()))
                .execute();
        return resp.getContent();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // An error occurred.
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
      }
    } else {
      // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
      return null;
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Title is the child folders name.      printFile(service,"0B3-sXIe4DGz1c3RhcnRlcl9")

Comment: I am not found this method. Please explain this method

Comment: Look at my answer the method is there.  Really you should try and read the documentation and the full answer for that matter.